# Chocolatey Ngrok.portable not working

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, nuget, chocolatey, ngrok

I have just install [Ngrok](https://chocolatey.org/packages/ngrok.portable) via [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) but I cannot get it to work, I have restarted the machine, tried adding the /ProgramData/chocolatey/Ngrok folder to the PATH environment variables, and running a variety of commands into CMD but no luck, CMD is telling me 'ngrok' is an unrecognised command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow up on the [package page](https://chocolatey.org/packages/ngrok.portable). Chocolatey.org packages are community maintained.

On the left side you will see a contact maintainers link, let them know. Also you might consider starting a disqus conversation at the bottom of the package page (maintainers may not monitor the thread but others could come across it and add some notes).

[image: Contact Maintainers]